# Why does not work done increase when power is increased?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, power

Suppose, a man pushes a wooden block through a distance of 2 m in 2 seconds and an other man pushes the same block to the same distance in 1 second. According to my assumption, the first man must have applied a lesser amount of force than the second man. This implies that the second man did more work on the block (since work done equals force times displacement), but in every cases as above, I have found that work done is equal and power is different. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You need more detail. What work are you doing to arrive at this conclusion?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that the blocks are being pushed at constant speed each time (even though the speed is greater when the second man pushes. This presupposes that the block is already moving at the right speed at the start of the 2 m. Since the speed is constant, the mens' pulls must be equal to the frictional drag. Assuming that the frictional drag is independent of speed (usually a fairly accurate assumption), the two men will have to apply equal forces, so the work done over the same distance will indeed be the same.

But suppose that the the block starts from rest each time. Then the men would have to apply a force greater than the frictional force, for at least part of the 2 m, in order to accelerate the block from rest. And the mean force needed would be greater for the second man, because the mean acceleration is greater. Perhaps this is why you said that "the first man must have applied a lesser amount of force than the second man". However, the statement that you see in textbooks that the work is independent of time taken, supposes a constant force, as I've outlined in my first paragraph.

Comment: What if the block was pushed in space?

Comment: If no other force acted on the block apart from a constant force from the man, and the block started from rest, 4 times the force would be needed to move the block through 2 m in 1 s than through 2 m in 2 s. Therefore the work done would be 4 times as much. But the textbooks aren't talking about moving a block; they're talking about applying a given force for a given distance – in which case the work done is independent of the time taken.